# How this stream's type is casted?

Tags: scala, types, casting, type-conversion

I'm wondering how the type of the Stream below is casted?

```
type NTy = BigInt
def streamFib(n: Int): NTy = {
  lazy val fibs: Stream[NTy] = 1 #:: 1 #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(n => n._1 + n._2)
  fibs.drop(n - 1).head
}
```

This compiles and `streamFib` returns a `BigInt` type (as expected?).

I also noticed a few more behaviors:

```
val s1:Stream[BigInt] = 1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty // incorrect, found Int required BigInt
val s2:Stream[BigInt] = 1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty[BigInt] // correct
val l1:List[BigInt] = 1 :: 2 :: List.empty[BigInt] // incorrect, found Any required BigInt
val l2:List[BigInt] = 1 :: BigInt(2) :: List.empty[BigInt] // correct
```

Answer (score 3):

#### tl;dr:

`fibs` is defined as a `Stream[BigInt]`, so when you prepend an `Int` to it (`1 #:: ...`), the compiler looks for an implicit conversion from `Int` to `BigInt` and finds it in `BigInt.int2bigInt`

---

---

There are a couple of things going on here.

1) The `BigInt` companion object defines an **implicit conversion** from `Int` to `BigInt`:

```
implicit def int2bigInt(i: Int): BigInt = apply(i)
```

This means that wherever you need a `BigInt` you can supply an `Int` and the implicit conversion will convert the value. You can also say that `Int`s can be *viewed as*  `BigInt`s.

2) methods that end with a colon are **right-associative**. This means that `1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty[BigInt]` can be effectively rewritten as `Stream.empty[BigInt].#::(2).#::(1)`

---

Now, if you look at the signature of `Stream.#::` (`def #::(hd: A): Stream[A]`) you'll see that `Stream[BigInt].#::(x)` can only compile if `x` is a `BigInt`.

When you call `1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty[BigInt]` you are calling `Stream[BigInt].#::` passing an `Int` value instead of a `BigInt`, but, as I mentioned earlier, `Int`s can be *viewed as* `BigInt`s, so they are automatically converted to BigInts and everything compiles.

---

When you do this: `val s1:Stream[BigInt] = 1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty` 
you are doing a different thing instead: you are creating on the right hand side a `Stream[Int]` (`Stream.empty` type is inferred to be Int from the 1,2 values you pass) and then you are assigning this value to a `Stream[BigInt]` val.

Unfortunately, there is no implicit conversion from `Stream[A]` to `Stream[B]`, even if `A` can be *viewed as* `B`, thus compilation fails.

You can define your own implicit conversion though:

```
implicit def asBigIntStream(xs: Stream[Int]): Stream[BigInt] = xs.map(BigInt.int2bigInt)
val s1:Stream[BigInt] = 1 #:: 2 #:: Stream.empty //This now works
```

---

There's something else going on with `List`s: differently from `Stream`, the `List` cons is defined as:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B]
```

With `Stream.#::(x)` you needed x to be the exact same type as the Stream you were prepending `x` to. With `List.::(x)`, instead, `x` (that has type `B`) can be an instance of a *supertype* of the list's type. The resulting list will be a `List[B]`, i.e. **prepending to a list can widen its type**.

So, when you do `2 :: List.empty[BigInt]` you're effectively Calling `List[A].::(x: B)` where `A` is `BigInt` and `B` is **inferred to be `Any` because `Any` is the most strict supertype of `BigInt` that is also a supertype of `Int`**.

Since this makes the compiler happy, no implicit conversions are looked for, and the resulting list is a List[Any] that you can't use anymore as a list of integers.

You can basically call `whatever :: List[X]` to get a `List[Y]` where `Y` is the most strict supertype of both `X` and the type of `whatever`

---

**So, why doesn't  `val l1:List[BigInt] = 1 :: 2 :: List.empty[BigInt]` work while  `val l2 : List[BigInt] = 1 :: BigInt(2) :: List.empty[BigInt]` does?**

It's because of *type inference*. Let's rewrite the two expressions removing the right-associativity:

```
val l1: List[BigInt] = (List.empty[BigInt].::(2)).::(1) // incorrect, found Any required BigInt
val l2: List[BigInt] = (List.empty[BigInt].::(BigInt(2))).::(1)  // correct
```

**I'm not 100% sure of this (anyone please correct me if I'm wrong)**:

- The compiler can help the type inference only on the last application of `::` 
  `(List.empty[BigInt].::(2))` is a `List[Any]` well before applying `.::(1)` so there's nothing we can do
- `(List.empty[BigInt].::(BigInt(2)))` is already a `List[BigInt]` and the compiler can try to make `.::(1)` a `BigInt` (thus looking for implicit conversions)

Comment: You skipped the most interesting case `val l1:List[BigInt] = 1 :: 2 :: List.empty[BigInt]` Why, for streams, implicit conversion kicks off but for lists it doesn't and results in `List[Any]`?

Comment: @Łukasz It took me some time to write the answer, this question is far more interesting than I thought at the beginning. I could be wrong about a couple of things but I think more or less that's it! Take a look at it and tell me what you think, feel free to edit :)

Comment: Yes, I think now you covered all there was to it. I never noticed before that stream does not widen the type when appending, now what happens is clear :)

Comment: I didn't as well! that's why I think this question is interesting :)

Comment: For `s1` I was wondering why it cannot be inferred since `val s:Stream[BigInt] = Stream.empty` actually compiles (not quite into type inference theory:-<).

Comment: Another problem is `what's the opportunity when implicit conversion is applied`? For example, `int2bigInt ` exists in BigInt.scala but not *import*ed in my module (e.g., `import scala.math.BigInt.int2bigInt`); I think you are absolutely here (e.g., `BigInt(1)+2` will get `BigInt(3)`) but I am personally confused about the specification.

Comment: still, why `streamFib` actually compiles and gets BigInt type?

Comment: @HongxuChen streamFib is a `Stream[BigInt]` (as per its own definition) and you prepend `Int`s to it that are implicitly converted to `BigInt`s, it's the same thing. I added it in the "tl;dr".

Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits) for the implicit resolution rules.

The implicit conversion is defined in BigInt's companion object, you don't need to import it

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti what i'm mostly confused about is that `Stream.empty` in `s1` cannot be inferred as `BigInt`. is there any spec about this? a quick glimpse of http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html doesn't help.

Comment: You are first evaluating the RHS (`Stream.empty.#::(2)` etc) and this leads to a Stream[Int]. I guess the compiler doesn't look at the LHS to build a successful RHS if it doesn't need to. With `l2` is different because you are prepending an `Int` to an already existing `List[BigInt]`, so implicit conversion kicks in.

Driving types from the LHS is a bit tricky in scala, I'm really not sure about this but I think the RHS type is evaluated first, then the compiler tries to assign it to the val. I guess some scala compiler expert will be able to tell you more about this